# How to maintain original scope of 'this' when passing a function around?

Tags: javascript, typescript, this

I have a function, call it `meow()`, as part of a class, call it `Cat`:

```
export class Cat(){

    private meow(){
        console.log(this);
    }
```

Now, say I have another class, call it `Kitten`, which takes a function as part of its constructor:

```
export class Kitten {

    var kittenMeow: { (): void; }; //note the typing

    constructor(functionForMeow : { (): void; }){ //note the typing
        this.kittenMeow = functionForMeow;
    }

    public meow(){
        this.kittenMeow();
    }
}
```

Now say I add the following to the `Cat` class:

```
export class Cat(){

    constructor(){
        this.giveBirth();
    }

    private meow(){
        console.log(this);
    }

    giveBirth(){
        var kitty = new Kitten(this.meow);
        kitty.meow();
    }
}
```

**When I run this code, "Kitten" is logged to the console. How can I make it so that "Cat" is logged to the console? That is, how do I preserve the original scope of `this` so that `this` refers to `Cat` and not `Kitten`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`.bind()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) in order to specify the value of `this` in the current scope. Then when the function is executed, `this` will refer to `Cat` rather than `Kitten`.

```
var kitty = new Kitten(this.meow.bind(this));
```

In other words, since `this` refers to `Cat` within the `giveBirth` method context, that is the value that is passed when executing the function in the other scope.

```
export class Cat {
  giveBirth() {
    var kitty = new Kitten(this.meow.bind(this));
    kitty.meow();
  }
}
```

Comment: I would also add that TypeScripts `fat arrows` don't capture `this` and you can annotate the callback type with `this` to explicitly require this to be a certain type. Reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this